# Best test to evaluate change over time in discrete non parametrical variables

Tags: nonparametric, dependent-variable

I have to analyze a database that includes a basal score from a functional status (score 0-10 in discrete intervals of 0.5) and a subsequent evaluation of the same subjects with a variable interval of time (30-2000 days), which could be the best test to use?

The distribution of the initial and subsequent evaluation score is non- parametric. Initially I was thinking of just using a Wilcoxon paired rank test but I will be missing the variable of time